# Loading Multiple Views In MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, layout

I have just switched from PHP CI(MVC) to ASP.NET MVC4 and also i am new to .net framework. I researched loading multiple views in MVC4 but i always found loading view with multiple Models and such....
What I am trying to do is load multiple view in a single page.

For eg:

I have a view left.cshtml

```
<div>Hello im on the left section</div>
@RenderBody();
```

and have next view main.cshtml

```
<div class="left"> // should come in the left section of the page
    @{Layout = "left.cshtml"}
</div>
<div class="right">
    Contents at the right and many more here
</div>
```

and from above what i expected is:

```
// Left section                     Right section

Hello im on the left section |  Contents at the right
                             |  and many more here
                             |
                             |
                             |
                             |
```

But The result was

```
Hello im on the left section
Contests at the right and many more here
```

and the CSS are also very ok.
Please help....

Comment: Looks ok, what was the result?

Comment: @Anarion i updated the result.Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking to render partial view. So use

```
@Html.Partial("ViewName")
```

### OR

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("ViewName");  }
```

Comment: is the `left` cshtml page?

Answer (score 0):

`Layout` is your main page, it goes "Around" of what is rendered via `RenderBody`. So, if you want to have your right section always same, and substitute different views to your left section you can create a layout containing "structure" of the page, and then render different views into it.
Your code should be:

layout.chtml:

```
<div class="left"> // should come in the left section of the page
 //Your left.chtml will be substituted here
   @RenderBody();
</div>
<div class="right">
    Contents at the right, they are always the same
</div>
```

left.chtml

```
//This line shows which layout you are going to use
@{Layout = "left.cshtml"}
//Whole code below is substitued in plase of "RenderBody" of your layout page
Contents at the left.
```

P.S you have to return the left view, not the laout view in your contoller.